# Calculate mean and std using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

I got a problem when I calculate the mean and std.

I loaded an CSV via

```
df = pandas.read_csv("fakedata.csv", skiprows=1, header=None)
```

but then the method

```
df.mean()
```

gives me nothing.
Here is the link of [raw data](https://github.com/JiaMingLin/privbayes/blob/master/resources/fakedata.csv).

```
>>> df.mean()
Series([], dtype: float64)
```

I have also checked the count.

```
>>> df.count()
0    40000
dtype: int64
```

My OS is Centos6.7 with python 2.7, pandas 0.17.1

```
pip show pandas
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: pandas
Version: 0.17.1
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series,and statistics
Home-page: http://pandas.pydata.org
Author: The PyData Development Team
Author-email: pydata@googlegroups.com
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: pytz, python-dateutil, numpy
```

[Edit]
The dataframe information shows

```
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 40000 entries, 0 to 39999
Data columns (total 1 columns):
0    40000 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 625.0+ KB
```

and dataframe shape shows

```
>>> df.shape
(40000, 1)
```

Comment: Impossible to comment without raw data to reproduce what does `df.info()` show and also `df.shape`?

Comment: @EdChum, thanks for your reply, I have added the link to raw data, and data frame information and shape

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, for me it works fine loading your data. I'm on Python 2.7.11 and pandas 0.17.1.

Comment: @JiaMingLin did you set the correct separator in `read_csv()`? Because the default is ',' but in your raw data seems to be a space. Try put `sep='\s+'` while reading the file.

Comment: @FabioLamanna, thanks for your comment, 
the truths is I have to specify the separator, the default is comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem relies on the separator. Copying and paste your file into a .csv file, I can read it with:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("fakedata.csv", skiprows=1, header=None, sep='\s+')
```

getting as result:

```
In [18]: df.mean()
Out[18]: 
0     50.574475
1     49.585400
2    169.478500
3     59.544800
4    119.814275
5     79.557500
6     79.497775
dtype: float64
```

and:

```
In [19]: df.std()
Out[19]: 
0    19.787459
1    19.762996
2    14.997920
3    10.034209
4    40.013550
5    19.887973
6    14.947894
dtype: float64
```

Comment: `delim_whitespace=True` will perform quicker here